# youtube start-index not working

Tags: php, youtube, feed

I'm trying to get a youtube playlist via the feed api. Since it's bigger then 50 items i would like to do multiple requests. At this time i have 55 items in my list so i would expect a start-index of 51 to return the last 4 results. However if i use start index, everything above 38 returns 0! This is the request i'm doing:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/Ac9sBdss4AXt6Iff6xO7xjOXSauzPw8m?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50&start-index=51

anybody noticed this before?

Regards,
Wouter